# Solving using Weak Duality

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, linear-programming

Using the weak duality theorem, solve the following problem
\begin{align*}
\text{minimise} \quad &6x_1 + 8x_2 + 19x_3 + 20x_4 \\
\text{subject to} \quad &2x_1 + x_2 + 3x_3 + x_4 \geq 1, \\
&x_1 + 2x_2 + 4x_3 + 5x_4 \geq 1, \\
&x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \geq 0.
\end{align*}

I found that the dual problem is:
\begin{align*}
\text{maximise} \quad &y_1 + y_2 \\
\text{subject to} \quad &2y_1 + y_2 \leq 6 \\
&y_1 + 2y_2 \leq 8 \\
&3y_1 + 4y_2 \leq 19 \\
&y_1 + 5y_2 \leq 20 \\
&y_1, y_2 \geq 0.
\end{align*}

I know if I find feasible solutions for both problems that give the same objective value, then they will be the optimal solutions. I am struggling to understand though how to pick the correct feasible solution that will give the maximum value though.

I sketch the constraints for the dual problem and pick the point $(1,1)$ inside the feasible region.

Do I have to use complimentary slackness to solve?